# Usage of until now

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Would it be possible to say "I had a normal life until now"? I have read that it is more common to use this expression "until now" with present perfect or past perfect, but I would like to know if it is also possible to use it with past simple.

Kind regards

Comment: In the right context it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "I have had a normal life until now".

Comment: Most Americans would not see an issue with that usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  "I had a normal life until now!"  I would expect to hear as an ironic or slightly annoyed (possibly passive-aggressive)retort to a third party, just after a mildly unpleasant or strange event had occurred, that caused some inconvenience to your normal daily life, for instance, you had just stepped in to a puddle, that turned out to be 60cm deep...

Depending upon the circumstances, if a little more formal or as part of a serious conversation, it may be better to say: "Until now, my life had been normal."...  This would imply that some thing had happened [The event], and your life had changed and become unusual, a little strange or unorthodox as a result.